# Using springs component-scan and injecting beans

Tags: spring, code-injection

Im using spring 2.5 and writing a DispatcherServlet. In the context file for the servlet im using component-scan and giving the location of the class where my controllers are. The classes use the @Controller("bean Name") annotation.

How can i inject properties into this bean?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also remember that you can inject beans defined in main application context to the beans defined in application context for servlet, but not vice-versa. These contexts aren't merged, but they form *parent-child* relationship.

Comment: cheers, i should have mentioned that i was using the Jetspeed Portal framework. Turns out beans created in the Jetspeed context were not available to the DispatcherServlet. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `@Autowired` ([docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation)) or `@Resource` ([docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-resource-annotation)).